# Preview picture in iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, preview

I got iPhone app.

When i start it, i see black view. This black view is shown before app's first view. And it looks really awful.

Can i set here preview picture?

Comment: This is where "default.png" is loaded. add such an image in your project and it will be displayed as the iOS loads your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can. add a images with "Default.png" & "Default@2x.png" - "D" capital in your resources. add them to your project as well.

dimensions will be for:

Default.png = 320x480 
Default@2x.png = 640x960

it will be used as splashscreen image which is lacking in your project.